# AWS rds high CPU utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, cpu

I'm facing high CPU issue, and I am aware of what caused the problem: I have a job that copy ~5G data from snowflake to aws rds. During this job running, I can see the aws rds CPU usage spikes, as well as the read/write throughput. What should I do to reduce/limit the cpu usage during that job running? Is there any configuration that I can tweak?

Comment: Do the job in smaller chunks or make the rds instance bigger

Comment: See if this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-instance-high-cpu/) helps.